# One website for support tickets, documentation, user management, file transfer, etc

Tags: joomla, confluence, vtiger

Does anyone know of a web app that can do all of the above in one place? We are currently working with Vtiger (support), Confluence (documentation), Joomla (website, user management & custom file transfer area).

We've tried using various Joomla components, but we've found nothing as good as the individual web apps listed above... We need something really robust & easy to use. And something that can be controlled with varying group permissions.

Cheers :)

Comment: What is the context you'll be using it for?  I don't want to jump out of turn but is sound like you may be looking at finding a developer who can deliver a piece of software tailored to these needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally use [Redmine](http://www.redmine.org/) for all of the mentioned needs.